# remove double Quotes while binding the data from SharePoint List Item to html textarea

Tags: jsom

I am binding the data for SharePoint list item as below .
But after binding the data I am getting the result in double quotations.

Can any one please help me in finding the issue in below lines

```
var txtparticipateidvalue="txtparticipants"+count;
var tempparticipantsvalues=oListItem.get_item('TTParticipants');
var wraper;
   if(tempparticipantsvalues!=null)
    {
    var wraper= '<textarea   id="'+txtparticipateidvalue+'"  disabled  rows="1" 
     cols="30" wrap="Hard">"'+tempparticipantsvalues+'" </textarea>';
          $(document).on("keyup", "textarea", check);
    }
    else
    {
     var wraper= '<textarea   id="'+txtparticipateidvalue+'"  disabled  rows="1" cols="30" wrap="Hard"> </textarea>';
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quotes from your strings:

```
var txtparticipateidvalue="txtparticipants"+count;
var tempparticipantsvalues=oListItem.get_item('TTParticipants');
var wraper;
if(tempparticipantsvalues!=null)
{
    var wraper= '<textarea   id="'+txtparticipateidvalue+'"  disabled  rows="1" cols="30" wrap="Hard">'+tempparticipantsvalues+'</textarea>';
    $(document).on("keyup", "textarea", check);
}
else
{
    var wraper= '<textarea   id="'+txtparticipateidvalue+'"  disabled  rows="1" cols="30" wrap="Hard"> </textarea>';
}
```

Comment: Could you please do let me know for which string I need to remove

Comment: You have the double quotes inside your string the first time you set the `wraper` variable. So `wrap="Hard">"'` should just be `wrap="Hard">'` and the same with the other side of the `tempparticipantsvalues`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var tempparticipantsvalues=oListItem.get_item('TTParticipants');
tempparticipantsvalues = tempparticipantsvalues.replace(/"/g, '');
```

That should remove the "" from your string.